# Postgres operator does not exist:

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Here's my code:

`.having('(COUNT(DISTINCT taggings.tag_id) = 0 OR array[?] <@ array_agg(taggings.tag_id))', tag_ids)`

I am getting the followint error when executing the above query:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] <@ integer[]
LINE 1: ...OUNT(DISTINCT taggings.tag_id) = 0 OR array[NULL] <@ array_a...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm new to the postgresql, can anyone please point the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly cast the array to `int[]`, because `array[null]` is resolved as `text[]`.

```
... OR array[?]::int[] <@ array_agg(taggings.tag_id)
```